# How do I implement search to happen across pages without making a call to the DB in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, search, pagination

I have a search function that works fine,, but only for the first page. I have implemented the pagination concept in my application. Here's my search function:

```
function Search() {

    var se = $('#SearchGrid').val().toUpperCase();
    var i, td;
    debugger;
    var x = document.getElementById("VolunteerGrid");
    var tr = x.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td) {
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(se) > -1) {
                tr[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                tr[i].style.display = "none";
            }
        }       
    }

}
```

I want this search function to get all the rows and not just the rows on the first page and show the result.

Here's my simple view:

```
<div id="VolunteerGrid">
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
            Email
        </th>
        <th>
            Phone Number
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var volunteer in Model)
    {
        //var id = volunteer.VolunteerId;
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => volunteer.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => volunteer.EmailAddress)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => volunteer.PhoneNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="Edit_btn" onclick ="EditVolunteer()">Edit</a> | <a href="#" id="Delete_btn">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("LoadVolunteers", new{page }))
```

I **do not** want to make a DB call to search my table. I know I can do that. Please look at the snapshot below

[image]

On the second page (not shown here), there's someone with letter 'E' in their name. When I search, it does not show the details of that person. It only takes the rows from the first page.

How do I return all the people based on the search input, **without** making a call to the DB? Thanks.

**Edited after Rohits suggestion** Still not working though

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using VMS.Controllers
@using VMS.Models
@using System.Web.Optimization
@using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office.CustomUI
@using MvcPaging
@using Alignment = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Math.Alignment
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

@model PagedList.IPagedList<VMS.Models.VolunteerInfo>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LoadVolunteer";
}


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<h2>
    Registered Volunteers

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-group-sm btn-success pull-right" id="Excel_Btn">Export to Excel</button>

    <img src="~/Images/search.png" width="20px" height="5px" style="position: fixed; margin: 0.4pc 0px 0pc 3.8pc; height: 4%;"/> <input type="text" id="SearchGrid" onkeyup="Search()" class="col-md-offset-1 customChanges" placeholder="Search for volunteer"/>

</h2>

<div id="VolunteerGrid">
    <table class="table" id="tblVolunteer">
        <tr>
            <th>
                Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Email
            </th>
            <th>
                Phone Number
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var volunteer in Model)
        {
            //var id = volunteer.VolunteerId;
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => volunteer.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => volunteer.EmailAddress)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => volunteer.PhoneNumber)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="Edit_btn" onclick="EditVolunteer()">Edit</a> | <a href="#" id="Delete_btn">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("LoadVolunteers", new {page}))
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#Excel_Btn').on('click',
            function() {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "ViewEditVolunteer")'

                });

            });

        $('#tblVolunteer').dataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/ViewEditVolunteerController/LoadVolunteers',
                "type": "GET",
                "dataType": 'json',
                "data": model
            },

            oLanguage: { "sZeroRecords": "No Records Found" },
            bDestroy: true,
            bFilter: false,
            bInfo: true,
            aaSorting: [],
            bLengthChange: false,
            columns: [
                { "sTitle": "Name", "data": "name" },
                { "sTitle": "Email", "data": "Email" },
                { "sTitle": "Phone No", "data": "phone" },
                { "sTitle": "Action", "data": "" }
            ],
            "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aaData) {
                $("td:eq(4)", nRow).html("<a onClick='EditVolunteerInfo(" +
                    aaData.VolunteerId +
                    ")'>Edit</a> | <a onClick='DeleteVolunteerInfo(" +
                    aaData.VolunteerId +
                    ")'>Delete</a>");
            }
        });

    });


    function Search() {

        var se = $('#SearchGrid').val().toUpperCase();
        var i, td;

        var x = document.getElementById("VolunteerGrid");
        var tr = x.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
            td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
            if (td) {
                if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(se) > -1) {
                    tr[i].style.display = "";
                } else {
                    tr[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }

    }

</script>
```

Comment: You need to have all the items (from all pages) previously loaded somehow. This could be done either via javascript (storing the data in the client's browser memory), or by making ajax calls to your backend API, which would have the data in a cache (possibly by user). Anyway, the answer to this question is very broad, it would help if you could be more specific.

Comment: Previously loaded? It is already loaded isin't it? I mean that's why I am getting all the rows right?

Comment: I have tried to be specific. Sorry if I wasn't specific enough. I want to search my table without making a call to my DB.

Comment: Just by looking your code I can't tell whether it's previously loaded or not. It looks everytime you change your current page, the `LoadVolunteers` action is called, thus making a new query on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on Rohits answer,

On your original table, just call this `$('#YourTableID').dataTable();`
It will solve your purpose.

Make sure you include

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@using System.Web.UI.WebControls
@using VMS.Controllers
@using VMS.Models
@using System.Web.Optimization
@using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Office.CustomUI
@using MvcPaging
@using Alignment = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Math.Alignment
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;

@model PagedList.IPagedList<VMS.Models.VolunteerInfo>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "LoadVolunteer";
 }

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<h2> Registered Volunteers  </h2>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-group-sm btn-success pull-right" id="Excel_Btn">Export to Excel</button>

<div id="VolunteerGrid">
    <table id="tblVolunteer"></table>    
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Excel_Btn').on('click',
            function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("ExportToExcel", "ViewEditVolunteer")'
                });
            });

        $('#tblVolunteer').dataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/ViewEditVolunteerController/LoadVolunteers',
                "type": "GET",
                "dataType": 'json',
                "data": model
            },

            oLanguage: { "sZeroRecords": "No Records Found" },
            bDestroy: true,
            bFilter: false,
            bInfo: true,
            aaSorting: [],
            bLengthChange: false,
            columns: [
                { "sTitle": "Name", "data": "name" },
                { "sTitle": "Email", "data": "email" },
                { "sTitle": "Phone No", "data": "phone" },
                { "sTitle": "Action", "data": "options" }
            ],
            "fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aaData) {
                $("td:eq(4)", nRow).html("<a onClick='EditVolunteerInfo(" +
                    aaData.VolunteerId +
                    ")'>Edit</a> | <a onClick='DeleteVolunteerInfo(" +
                    aaData.VolunteerId +
                    ")'>Delete</a>");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

### Please Note: In the above datatable columns "sTitle" represents your *table headers* and "data" is just the mapping of your JSON response objects mapped in the datatable..

**ViewEditVolunteerController.cs**

```
public JsonResult LoadVolunteers()  
{      
  List<Volunteers> listVol = new List<Volunteers>();
  //this is just one object for your understanding purpose, you may call service here to read the data from database
  var result= listVol.Add(new Volunteer
              {
                 name="XYZ", 
                 email="xyz@hotmail.com",
                 phone="0000000454",
                 options=""
              });
  return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
}
```

Comment: HI. Thank you so much for your effort. But for some reason it didn't work.  I tried to debug and I think the execution is not reaching the controller. It didn't hit the break point in my controller. I also think `dataTable` is not getting recognized. Because it's not showing in intelisense.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery DataTable plugin instead of what you did above that will be more flexible to implement and can handle huge records, It's open source.

Please refer: https://datatables.net/ for more info.

Make ajax call and bind the json response in the DOM something like below:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    ajax: {
        url: '/api/myData',
        dataSrc: ''
    },
    columns: [ ... ]
} );
```

Comment: This looks like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to say here. Can you please add a little detail?

Comment: @PriyankaDembla, I have provided code snippet for your reference to implement the jQuery DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="tblVolunteer" class="display" style="width:100%">

------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tblVolunteer').dataTable({
                "ajax": {
                    "url": '/HomeController/LoadVolunteerDetails',
                    "type": "GET",
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "data": model
                },

                oLanguage: { "sZeroRecords": "No Records Found" },
                bDestroy: true,
                bFilter: false,
                bInfo: true,
                aaSorting: [],
                bLengthChange: false,
                columns: [
                    { "sTitle": "Name", "data": "name" },
                    { "sTitle": "Email", "data": "email" },
                    { "sTitle": "Phone No", "data": "phone" },
                    { "sTitle": "Action", "data": ""}              
                ],    
                "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aaData) { 
                    $("td:eq(4)", nRow).html("<a onClick='EditVolunteerInfo(" + aaData.VolunteerId + ")'>Edit</a> | <a onClick='DeleteVolunteerInfo(" + aaData.VolunteerId + ")'>Delete</a>");
                }          
            });       
        }});
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**In addition to the above code, the following two Javascript library files must be added:**

https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

**The following CSS library files must be added for use to provide the styling of the table:**

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

Please refer this link for more details: [refer this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)

Comment: Hi Rohit. Tried your code but not sure if I have implemented it correct. I have edited my question. It has the full LoadVolunteers.cshtml code. Please tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Rohit. Could you please look into my code above and tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi Priyanka, What error you are getting? I looked your cshtml(view) but you should remove other code present inside <div id="VolunteerGrid"> and keep only table element with Id like below:<table id="tblVolunteer" class="display" style="width:100%">. You need to bind the json response  which will be returned from the ActionMethod present in the controller.

Comment: Please keep your Javascript code in separate .js file and reference that in View. In this way your code will be more cleaner. Thank you.